# replacing html in chrome extension javascript

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, replace, google-chrome-extension

I'm loading a page and I want to load an alternate file on the same host. The file is chat.swf normally; however, i'd like it to be replaced with a chat2.swf which is stored at the same location.

How would I go about doing this? I tried deleting the div and recreating, but I can't even get my script to delete the correct div (i think it executes before it's even done loading)

the script to remove the div works when I insert it in the url bar (using javascript: method)

It'd be best if I could just use something in the chrome extension API, but i'm not quite sure how to do it :\ thanks in advance :D

EDIT (code):

```
function deleteOldChat() {
 elem = document.getElementByID("chat");
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, deleteOldChat);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [WebRequestAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html) should allow you to intercept URL requests and rewrite them to do something else.

> Use the chrome.experimental.webRequest module to intercept, block, or modify requests in-flight.

So when you see a request to the old swf you can rewrite it to the other version.

`onBeforeRequest` happens before a request is actually submitted, so that would be a good point to modify the request:

> onBeforeRequest
>
> chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(object details) {...}, RequestFilter filter, array of string extraInfoSpec));
>
> Fires when a request is about to occur.